# 15 digit floating variable calculation in microcontroller

Tags: algorithms, calculator

I want to calculate an equation within a controller(Arduino)

> y = -0.0000000104529251928664x^3 + 0.0000928316793270531x^2 - 0.282333029643959x + 297.661280719026

Now the decimal values of the coefficients are important because "x" varies in thousands so cube term cannot be ignored. I have tried manipulating the equation in excel to reduce the coefficients but R^2 is lost in the process and I would like to avoid that.

[image]

Max variable size available in Arduino is 4byte. And on google search, I was not able to find an appropriate solution.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So let me get this straight: this polynomial (red on the graph) is a cubic match to the points (blue dots); you wish to calculate the results as accurately as possible, but you only get single-precision floating points and your numbers are double precision floating points?

Comment: Yes. The answer (Y in this case) that is relevant to me won't be greater than 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: 4 bytes is only single precision, some 7 digits. You can encode a double in two 4 byte variables, but you'd need a library for doing maths with that. I bet there are such libraries.

Comment: You could just... use single precision floating points.  The numbers aren't so small that they are unrepresentable even approximately.

Comment: Have you tried Hörner polynomial evaluation instead of monomial $x^n$ evaluation ? It has generally more stability. $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=((ax+b)x+c)x+d$

Comment: there was small miscommunication and I was asked to post my question on this forum. But I have found my answer on SOF. So i am posting the link of the same. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635183/15-digit-floating-variable-calculation-in-microcontroller/46635291#46635291

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the Arduino specifications, the number
$-0.0000000104529251928664$
will be rounded to approximately $-0.00000001045293.$
In scientific notation, that's
$$ 1.045293 \times 10^{-8}. $$

You'll lose some precision because only four-byte floating-point numbers are supported, but you won't lose the $x^3$ term completely.
In fact it will be very nearly as accurate (relative to its mathematically correct value) as any of the other terms.

On the other hand, what happens to $R^2$ if you divide the $x$ coordinate of every data point by $2000$ and use the equation
\begin{multline}
y = -83.6234015429312 x^3 + 371.3267173082124 x^2 \\ - 564.666059287918 x + 297.661280719026?
\end{multline}

Comment: Typo: The number should be $ 1.045293 \times 10^{-8}. $

Comment: @gammatester Well spotted! I think it's fixed now.

Comment: Even better, divide every number by $2048$ and you won't lose any bits

Comment: @DanUznanski Or just let the floating-point arithmetic do its job, which I think will come out to the same thing in the end. But division by $2048$ (or another power of $2$) becomes interesting if that (combined with some other tricks) makes it possible to do the calculations accurately in integers. That may end up losing some accuracy in the end, however; I haven't worked it through to find out.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the accuracy by defining $u=x-2500$ and rewriting your polynomial in terms of $u$.  It doesn't help much in this case, but the maximum value of $u^3$ is about $10^9$ where $x^3$ goes up to about $43 \cdot 10^9$.  Your equation does not seem to have any spectacular cancellation, so computing in single precision should be fine.  The fact that the cubic term starts with a bunch of zeros will be taken care of by the floating point.  You will have about seven decimal digits of numerical accuracy, which is more than is justified by the fit you have.